# Unable to iterate on the content of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contents data that I can see on doing a `var_dump()` but I am unable to iterate through its content using `foreach()`

The `var_dump()` generates the following output

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Admin" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "rick" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "techbr" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "testdom" } }
```

I want to be able to get the content of this array and store it in another.

Currently I am using the following code

```
$empList = array();
$empList = emp_list($mysqli);
var_dump($empList);//This generated the above output
foreach ($empList as $value)
{
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Output of the echo is this

```
Array
Array
Array
Array
```

How do I sort this out?

Thank you for your suggestions I have modified the code this way

```
$i=0;
$empList = array();
$tempList = array();
$tempList = emp_list($mysqli);
foreach ($tempList as $value)
{
    $empList[$i] = $value[0];
    $i++;
}
```

Now the `$empList` array stores stuff in the correct format

Comment: Your array consists of more arrays. Either use `var_dump` to see what you have or iterate again. Or `$value[0]`

Comment: You should use $value[0]; because $value is an array in which the first element is the string.

Comment: You currently have a multi dimensional array, your foreach loop is only iterating around elements in the first dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has an array inside another array so, use two foreach loops

```
$empList = array();
$empList = emp_list($mysqli);

foreach ($empList as $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $temp)
    {
        echo $temp."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As u_mulder says in the comments on your question, your array isn't an array of strings - it's an array of more arrays. var_dump() is designed to deal with complicated nested contents, but echo can't print arrays - that's why it's just telling you that each item in $empList is an array, and not what its contents are.

If you wanted to get the content out of a specific array in $empList you'd need to access it by its index key, with something like:

```
$first = $empList[0];
foreach ($first as $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Or if you wanted to iterate through them all you could just put two foreach loops one inside the other.